# edit Java Script to deviate a certain key and assign different values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to customize show apps icon..

tried to edit the java script

```
var ShowAppsIcon = new Lang.Class({
    Name: 'ShowAppsIcon',
    Extends: DashItemContainer,

    _init() {
        this.parent();

        this.toggleButton = new St.Button({ style_class: 'show-apps',
                                            track_hover: true,
                                            can_focus: true,
                                            toggle_mode: true });
        this._iconActor = null;
        this.icon = new IconGrid.BaseIcon(_("Show Applications"),
                                           { setSizeManually: true,
                                             showLabel: false,
                                             createIcon: this._createIcon.bind(this) });
        this.toggleButton.add_actor(this.icon.actor);
        this.toggleButton._delegate = this;

        this.setChild(this.toggleButton);
        this.setDragApp(null);
    },

    _createIcon(size) {
        this._iconActor = new St.Icon({ icon_name: 'view-app-grid-symbolic',
                                        icon_size: size,
                                        style_class: 'show-apps-icon',
                                        track_hover: true });
        return this._iconActor;
    },
```

this script is working as a single script for the favorite apps icons and show apps icon.

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04.
I am trying to customize the "show-apps" Icon.

Here is the Java Script file. https://superuser.com/questions/1431374/ubuntu-18-04-customize-show-apps-icon

Please have a look on below imgaes with Show-Apps button at bottom right with yellow and green color.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Question: Is it possible to alter the attached Java Script file, so that I can customize the Width of the Show-Apps Icon size keeping Show-Apps Icon Height Unchanged from the script so that when I increase the Dock Icon Size from System Settings..I will have constant height but variable width only for show apps Icon based on entire dock height.

Comment: I guess **no**. imo. the relevant line for you is this one: `icon_size: size` and on a quick look into the docs, [St.Icon](https://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/st-st-icon.html) doesn't seem to have distinct properties for width and height.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for your response.. so shall i leave the hope.. or can wait for some one to look into this?